# how to read decimal value from file in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to read decimal value from file and but it's giving me error: Input string is not in correct format
the code that I've written is:

```
void Start()
{
    fileName = "assets/names.txt";
   
    myFilePath = fileName;

    namesArray = File.ReadAllLines(myFilePath);
    DisplayAllStudents();
    

}
void DisplayAllStudents()
{
  
    System.Array.Sort(namesArray);
    foreach (string line in namesArray)
    {
        string[] field = line.Split(',');
       
        
        createSphere(field);
   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post an example of the decimal value that you are trying to read and the code that you have used to read it.

Comment: @Steve 0,1,90,3
3,1.5,0,2  
like i want to read 1.5

Comment: please put code for function createSphere, I suppose that you try to cast string to decimal in that function?

Comment: _3 3_ this is not a valid number for whatever parser you are using.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys i was using Int32.parse instead of float.parse love you guys @TJacken

Comment: and @Steve bro too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be save on wheather decimal separator you parse for different countries, use a fixed Culture like so:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo c = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us");
double[] field2 = field.Select(f => { double d; if (double.TryParse(f, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number, c, out d)) { return d; } else { return 0; }}).ToArray();
```